# Sorting a Singly Linked List with Time Complexity O(nlogn) and Space Complexity O(1)

Tags: time-complexity, mergesort, singly-linked-list, space-complexity

I am having difficulty figuring out an algorithm to sort a singly linked list with time complexity of O(nlgn) and space complexity of O(1) for an assignment.

For the time complexity issue, I have tried using merge sort but it seems that my recursive solution may have space complexity issues.

I have read around and have found remarks that this is not possible using recursion.
Is this true?

Would someone be able to provide some rough pseudo code or in Java to can answer this?

Comment: Are you sure this is possible?

Comment: Were you able to do it?